# A bound on the size of the center

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups, free-groups, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, $F$ a free pro-$p$ group, $H \leq_c F$ of infinite index. Can it be that $$\sup_{N \lhd_o F} |Z((F/N)/C_{F/N}(HN/N))| < \infty ?$$

Comment: Why is $C_{F/N}(HN/N)$ normal in $F/N$?

Comment: @HJRW: For groups $A \leq B$ I write $C_{B}(A)$ for the normal core of $A$ in $B$ - the intersection of all conjugates of $A$ in $B$. This is the largest normal subgroup of $B$ contained in $A$.

Comment: Oh, right. I thought it was the centralizer.